# smaller & nicer select with bootstrap.css

Tags: jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap

Of course I know that SELECT form elements are hard to style and/or modify beyond the basics.

Just out of curiosity, does anyone know of a one-off bootstrap (the one from twitter) solution that would allow me to affect the size of the SELECT and perhaps even apply a gradient that looks more like a bootstrap button (than the scratchy surface they have now).

I don't mind noodling around with the CSS myself, but I thought I'd ask around before re-inventing the wheel.

Any pointers, links or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the jQuery plugin bootstrap-select:

https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/

It will turn your select into a bootstrap button dropdown

Comment: **Hey silvio, that's really cool stuff.** That's the kind of stuff I'm looking for, thank you very much. If you happen to know of any other TWITTER-BOOTSTRAP-LIKE elements or additions, please let me know. Thank you very much!

Comment: Ace, I used [timepicker](http://jdewit.github.com/bootstrap-timepicker/) and [datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/)

Comment: I just came around this and I have a question.If you check your DOM after having the css and JS needed and ofcourse applying the "selectpicker" class on your select you'll see that what this plugin does is duplicate your selector options in a new DIV and then hides your original select tag...should this be worrying at any point??

Comment: ...btw things seem a bit broken if I had a "pull-right" class on my selector.The created DIV will be ltr.Only if float:right is added it gets moving

Comment: please open an issue and if possible provide a jsfiddle to fix it

Comment: amazing plugin! just one question (not related with the answer)...how can I make that if I have 3 values... the title still shows at first? like "nothing selected" but... if i have values it shows first value. Thanks again for that plugin!

Answer (score 4):

A bit late but maybe this can help http://blog.iamjamoy.com/docs/select.html

or this http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/

The first one doesn´t work on IE, if you can fix it please provide.

Comment: **Thank you alejandro.** This is a "nice to have" solution, and I appreciate your help very much. Thank you.

Comment: That doesn't work on IE10 (no surprise) - haven't tested others.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function($){
        $('select').each(function(i, e){
            if (!($(e).data('convert') == 'no')) {
                //$(e).hide().wrap('<div class="btn-group" id="select-group-' + i + '" />');
                $(e).after('<div class="btn-group" id="select-group-' + i + '" />');
                var select = $('#select-group-' + i);
                var current = ($(e).val()) ? $(e).val(): '&nbsp;';
                select.html('<input type="hidden" value="' + $(e).val() + '" name="' + $(e).attr('name') + '" id="' + $(e).attr('id') + '" class="' + $(e).attr('class') + '" /><a class="btn" href="javascript:;">' + current + '</a><a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:;"><span class="caret"></span></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"></ul>');
                $(e).find('option').each(function(o,q) {
                    select.find('.dropdown-menu').append('<li><a href="javascript:;" data-value="' + $(q).attr('value') + '">' + $(q).text() + '</a></li>');
                    if ($(q).attr('selected')) select.find('.dropdown-menu li:eq(' + o + ')').click();
                });
                select.find('.dropdown-menu a').click(function() {
                    select.find('input[type=hidden]').val($(this).data('value')).change();
                    select.find('.btn:eq(0)').text($(this).text());
                });
                $(e).remove();
            }
        });
    });
```